# Knn Classifier with squared iverse weights in python( weight is a callable function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to apply kNN classifer with squared inverse weights
using sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier package.
According to the documentation we can define a function for the weights. I defined the follwing function  to obtain the squareed inverse of the distances as the weights:

```
import numpy as np
def isd():
    w= []
    for i in range(len(x_train)):
        # first we compute the euclidean distance
        distance = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(x_test 
        x_train[i,:])))
        # add it to list of distances
        w.append([1/(np.square(distance)), i]) 
        return w
```

and then I used the KNeighborsClassifier as follow:

```
neighbors = list(range(1,11))
#making an empty vector to store accuracy scores
ac_scores3= []
# fitting the model
for K in neighbors:
    K_value = K+1
    knn3= KNeighborsClassifier(K_value,weights=isd())
    knn3.fit(x_train,y_train.values.ravel()) 
    y_pred3=knn3.predict(x_test)
    ac_scores3.append(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred3))

# finding test error by subtracting ac from 1
TE3 = [1 - x for x in ac_scores3]
```

I am getting the following error:

### ValueError: weights not recognized: should be 'uniform', 'distance', or a callable function

by the way I am using usps data set, Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isd` is your callable but `isd()` is a call and evaluates to the return value of the call.

So, use `weights=isd` without the `()`.

Comment: Thanks Janne, I chamged isd() to weights=isd and that definitely fixed one of my mistakes, I also had to change my isd function though.