# How to make user-defined callable weight function for sklearn knn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, callable, weighted

I am trying to make custom weights for Sklearn KNN classifier, similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393979/knn-classifier-with-squared-iverse-weights-in-python-weight-is-a-callable-funct). 
In documentation is just briefly mentioned that you can set custom weights as *a user-defined function which accepts an array of distances, and returns an array of the same shape containing the weights.* [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier).

How can I make that function for squared distance or linear weights?
I went trough countless pages of SO, but without any luck.
Is there a walkthrough or correct example?